How to replace column value without losing the style?
This is my styled dataframe:

What I want is to change send the value of aEV to aEV_percentile, but without losing the styles, or to be much more specific, without losing the background color of aEV_percentile. This is my messy code:
gradient = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ['blue', 'white', '#f81707'])

data_style = players_data_df.style.format(mapper)
.background_gradient(subset=['aEV'], cmap=gradient,
vmin=players_data_df.aEV.min(),
vmax=players_data_df.aEV.max())

data_style = data_style
.background_gradient(subset=['aEV_percentile'], cmap=gradient,
vmin=players_data_df.aEV_percentile.min(),
vmax=players_data_df.aEV_percentile.max())


I have tried this:
data_style.data['aEV_percentile'] = data_style.data['aEV']

But aEV_percentile lost its style. It takes exactly aEV style
Maybe this is not posible. I want to do this because I feel aEV_percentile gradient color is better representative for the percentile scale.

In fact, you just need to make a copy of your dataframe and apply the styles to the new dataframe using the values from the old one. I just added a minimal reproducible dataframe:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib

aEV = [95.8, 94.0, 93.9, 92.5, 91.8, 91.5, 90.9, 90.3, 89.3, 89.1, 88.8, 87.8]
aEV_percentile = [100, 98, 96, 94, 92, 90, 88, 85, 83, 81, 79, 77]

df = pd.DataFrame({'aEV': aEV, 'aEV_percentile': aEV_percentile})

new_df = df.copy()
gradient = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ['blue', 'white', '#f81707'])
data_style = new_df.style.background_gradient(subset=['aEV'], cmap=gradient,
                                                       vmin=df.aEV.min(),
                                                       vmax=df.aEV.max())

new_df['aEV_percentile'] = new_df['aEV']
data_style = data_style.background_gradient(subset=['aEV_percentile'], cmap=gradient,
                                            vmin=df.aEV_percentile.min(),
                                            vmax=df.aEV_percentile.max())

data_style

The result from this code is the following:

